# Laravel relation returning empty

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get all the books under a certain category. The category has many subjects and books are linked to subjects.

My code:

```
class BookCategory extends Model {

    public function subjects() {
        return $this->hasMany('BookSubject', 'category_id', 'id');
    }

    public function getBooksAttribute() {
        return Books::whereHas('subjects', function ($query) {
            return $query->join('book_category', 'book_category.id', '=', 'book_subject.subject_id')
                         ->where('book_category.id', $this->id);
        })->get();
    }
}
```

and my Books model:

```
class Books extends Model {

    public function subjects() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('BookSubject', 'book_by_subject', 'book_id', 'subject_id');
    }
}
```

If I do:

```
$cats = \App\Models\BookCategory::all();
foreach ($cats as $c) {
    echo $c->books->count();
}
```

It's always returning 0 for all the rows. What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your subquery:

```
return $query->join('book_category', 'book_category.id', '=', 'book_subject.subject_id')
                     ->where('book_category.id', $this->id);
```

I'm pretty sure `book_subject.subject_id` should be `book_subject.category_id`

Hard to tell without seeing your db schema.

Comment: Hahah . I feel so dumb and studid now . Thanks buddy @Pitchinnate

Comment: No problem we all have done the same type of thing a hundred times.